# Changes in html page not being saved to disk

Tags: html

I wrote a simple html unit containing some text boxes and option buttons:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0047)file:///C:/Users/akumar8/Desktop/checklist.html -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></head><body>
<h1>Stock Pre-Review Checklist</h1>
<form>
    <table style="width:100%" border="1">
        <tbody><tr><th bgcolor="SpringGreen"> <font color="black">#</font></th>
        <th bgcolor="SpringGreen"> <font color="black">Stock Pre-Review Guideline</font></th>
        <th bgcolor="SpringGreen"> <font color="black">Yes</font></th>      
        <th bgcolor="SpringGreen"> <font color="black">No</font></th>
        <th bgcolor="SpringGreen"> <font color="black">N/A</font></th>
        <th bgcolor="SpringGreen"> <font color="black">Comments</font></th>
        </tr><tr bgcolor="LightGrey">
        <td width="2%"> 1 </td>
        <td width="70%"> Is the stock in place?</td>
        <td width="5%"> <input checked="checked" name="design_discussion" value="Yes" type="radio"> Yes</td>
        <td width="5%"> <input name="design_discussion" value="No" type="radio"> No</td>
        <td width="5%"> <input name="design_discussion" value="N/A" type="radio"> N/A</td>
        <td width="13%"> <textarea name="textarea" style="width:250px;height:75px;"></textarea>  </td>
        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor="DarkGrey">
        <td width="2%"> 2 </td>
        <td> Is the inventory aligned with the upcoming requirement?</td>
        <td>   <input name="req_acc_unamb_noncon" value="Yes" type="radio"> Yes</td>
        <td>   <input checked="checked" name="req_acc_unamb_noncon" value="No" type="radio"> No</td>
        <td>   <input name="req_acc_unamb_noncon" value="N/A" type="radio"> N/A</td>
        <td> <textarea name="textarea" style="width:250px;height:75px;"></textarea>  </td>
        </tr>
   </tbody></table>
</form>
```

When I open this unit in **Chrome/Internet Explorer browser** and enter some text along with some changes in the option buttons and then save the webpage, I see that the changes are not getting saved on the disk and all those changes gets lost when I reopen the saved html file. **However, the same thing works when I use Mozilla Firfox browser.**

[image]

What is going wrong here?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There may be two files with same name and you may opening different file. go to that location when you change something. and open that file in text editor confirm that changes saved or not.

Comment: How do you edit the file with you internet browser ? If you update with the debugger the source file, this is not the file on the disk, you can't save it. I never heard anything about editing file with this web browser, if someone can confirm.

Comment: It does not save the inputs to text boxes etc. I just saves the HTML sent from the server.

Comment: But, the same thing works when I use Mozilla Firfox browser.

Answer (score 2):

The inspector is made to preview changes not to edit html files. I recommend you to use some appropriate IDE to edit your HTML, for example Brackets or Notepad++.

Comment: The same thing works when I use Mozilla Firfox browser.

Comment: I know, but it is more likely to be a bug or project decision. One proof for that is that you didn't close your HTML tags. When you save, firefox closes for you your tags as well as he saves every state, your inputs values for example.

Comment: so is ther anyway we can control this from the html source unit?

Comment: Do you mean dinamically see the result in your browser? There are a few options. Dreamweaver and gulp with the right plugins are some that I know exist but never used them. I always change the HTML and reload the browser(F5 or ctrl+R) when I'm working, so I can test some changes on the browser before save them in my html source code.

Comment: I was thinking if we can write back to the html source unit from the browser?, Like it worked in firefox!